# Recovery from seed not working on monero.mac.x64.v0-9-4-0

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

Whenever I proceed according to these instructions: https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/restore_account

And type: `simplewallet –restore-deterministic-wallet`

It just returns:

```
-bash: simplewallet: command not found
```

Are there any formatting mistakes that I am making that are causing this error?

Comment: Either compile simplewallet, copy it onto your computer, or give path to it if it is. It seems to not be found in your PATH.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on user36303's post … Adding the directory location, where Monero's binaries reside, to your `PATH` variable, is just as simple as adding a line such a the following to the end of the `.profile` file in your home directory (in the below example, the Monero directory is `/opt/monero`).

```
PATH="${PATH}:/opt/monero"
```

This will avoid the `command not found` error. Next, you can check if the `PATH` edit works properly:

```
mac:~ dpzz$ which simplewallet
/opt/monero/simplewallet
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a formatting issue with the website. The correct command is indeed `./simplewallet --restore-deterministic-wallet`. Note that flags always start with `--` and not `–`. Thus, if you ever encounter that again in a guide, ignore it and use `--`.